# C++ non-static data member initializers, just a little bit confused

Tags: c++, c++11

I am a little bit confused about why the following code does what it does:

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base() = default;
    Base(const Base &) =delete;
    Base &operator=(const Base &) = delete;
    Base(const char*) {}
};

class Holder
{
public:
    Holder() = default;
private:
    // Base b = Base();
    Base b2 = {};
};

int main()
{
    Holder h;
}
```

in this incarnation, it compiles, however if I un-comment `Base b = Base();` it gives the following error:

```
main.cpp:15:17: error: use of deleted function 'Base::Base(const Base&)'
   Base b = Base();
                 ^
main.cpp:5:6: note: declared here
      Base(const Base &) =delete;
      ^
```

and I am just unable to find in the standard why it tries to call the copy constructor for the `Base b = Base()` initializer, and why doesn't it call for the `Base b2 = {}` ... or is this just one of those little obscurities that is hidden in a few words in a paragraph somewhere?

Can you please give a (short) explanation why this happens?

(coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c02ba0293eab2ce5 )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because, conceptually, that line constructs from `Base()`, which requires a copy/move constructor. The probable reason why you weren't aware of this, is because that expression generally triggers copy elision: a standard optimization. It's one of those C++ gotcha's.

> (31.3) — when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a
>   reference (12.2) would be copied/moved to a class object with the same
>   cv-unqualified type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by
>   constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the
>   omitted copy/move.

As for why `Base b2 = {}` works, see

> (3.4) — Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements and T is a
>   class type with a default constructor, the object is
>   value-initialized.

You could just do `Base b;`.

Comment: Even when copy/move is elided, it should be accessible.

Comment: Even when the initializer has an element, the copy/move still doesn't happen. http://rextester.com/NITD75273

Comment: @0x499602D2 In that case it's not an initializer_list, it's just list initialization (or a braced-init-list). "If the previous stage does not produce a match, all constructors of T participate in overload resolution against the set of arguments that consists of the elements of the braced-init-list..."

Comment: Thanks. But note that it was never an initializer_list in any case, it was always a braced-init-list.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Yep, you said "initializer list" so I pedantically corrected. But then, as noted, the code you submitted simply calls the `(const char*)` constructor.

Comment: No I said "initializer". :)

Comment: @0x499602D2 You're right, my bad. Anyway, looks like the question is cleared up. :)

Answer (score 5):

`T object = {arg1, arg2, ...};` is syntax for [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization). There is no copying involved.

`T object = T()` is not list initialization. The right hand operand constructs a value-initialized temporary, and `object` is move- or copy-initialized from it. The move and copy can be elided, but the type must be movable or copyable, otherwise this is not allowed.

Comment: `Base` is not an aggregate because it has a user-provided constructor `Base(const char*)`.

Comment: @BaummitAugen indeed. It's list initialization, right?

Comment: Yes, more precisely *"copy-list-initialization"* which in this case value initializes `Base`, i.e. calls its default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The true reason is because you forget keyword "explicit", you should change the code

```
Base(const Base &) =delete;
```

To:

```
explicit Base(const Base &) = delete;
```

Let me explain the reason, In class "Holder", Base b = Base() will:

1. Base() will generate a temporary object by calling constructor "Base()"
2. However, constructor "Base(const Base&)" has a **single** parameter and without keyword "explicit", this will make code:

`Base obj = value;`

become

`Base obj(value);`

Therefore, just add keyword "explicit" will solve this problem.  ^_^